# Issues with reading/uploading .csv files with php on mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

So I tried to build web "app" with PHP that imports bank statements form .CSV file to mySQL database. But unfortunately my code has still some flaws, for example when i run this code everything works fine except:

1. if .CSV file contains special characters like (š,ž,č) or ","(for float numbers) than it reads like new array, but i want to replace "," with "." so that mySQL recognize number as float and replace special characters with similar characters (s,z,c).
2. if i have a header in .csv file i wish to skip this header(first row), probably the easiest way would be to first read file and count rows, so that i get maximum number of rows in file, and than use maybe while or for loop? like while(($row>=2)

```
<?php
    $conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','admin','admin','database_test');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $createTable="CREATE TABLE Bank_statements(
        id INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        date DATE NOT NULL,
        purpose TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
        debit FLOAT(255,2) NOT NULL,
        kredit FLOAT(255,2) NOT NULL
        );";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$createTable)){
            $file=fopen($_FILES['file_nkbm']['tmp_name'],"r");
            while($data=fgetcsv($file)){
                foreach($data as $dat){
                    $expl=explode(";",$dat);
                    $convert_date=strtotime($expl[4]);
                    $date=date('y-m-d',$convert_date);
                    $debit=doubleval($expl[5]);
                    $kredit=doubleval($expl[6]);
                    $purpose=$expl[8];
                    $addData="INSERT INTO Bank_statements(date,debit,kredit,purpose) VALUES 
                    ('$date','$debit','$kredit','$purpose');";
                    if (mysqli_query($conn,$addData)){
                        echo "success";
                    }else{
                        echo "fail".mysqli_error($conn);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($_FILES['file_nkbm']['tmp_name']);
            $query="SELECT * FROM Bank_statements;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['id'].$row['date'].$row['purpose'].$row['debit'].$row['kredit']."<br>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "table already exist";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

result is ok if i try to edit .csv file manually but that's not the point or goal of program.

Comment: Throw away line 1 = Just read a line before the while loop and throw it away ( i.e. dont do anything with it

Comment: Change `,` to `.` with `str_replace(',', '.', The field with the comma in)`

Comment: You're currently doing your (attempted) row logic at the column level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a right result, so my code currently looks like that:

```
<?php
    $conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','admin','admin','database_test');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $createTable="CREATE TABLE Bank_statements(
        id INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        date DATE NOT NULL,
        purpose TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
        debit FLOAT(255,2) NOT NULL,
        kredit FLOAT(255,2) NOT NULL
        );";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$createTable)){
            $file=fopen($_FILES['file_nkbm']['tmp_name'],"r");
            $row=1;
            while($data=fgetcsv($file,1000,'~')){
                $repl_one=str_replace(',','.',$data);
                $repl=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/','?',$repl_one);
                $row++;
                if ($row!=2){
                    foreach($repl as $dat){
                        $expl=explode(";",$dat);
                        $convert_date=strtotime($expl[4]);
                        $date=date('y-m-d',$convert_date);
                        $debit=doubleval($expl[5]);
                        $kredit=doubleval($expl[6]);
                        $purpose=$expl[8];
                        $addData="INSERT INTO Bank_statements(date,debit,kredit,purpose) 
                                  VALUES ('$date','$debit','$kredit','$purpose');";
                        mysqli_query($conn,$addData);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($_FILES['file_nkbm']['tmp_name']);
            $query="SELECT * FROM Bank_statements;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['id'].$row['date'].$row['purpose'].$row['debit'].$row['kredit']."<br>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "table already exist";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

with variable `$row` i solved the issue of skipping first row and with `str_replace` and `preg_replace` i solved problem with dot, and special characters in a file. But i had to set `fgetcsv` delimiter to some character other than "," because when program read the file it splitted one row into new array when it encountered ",".